# @angular/cli 4 wont install on debian

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, angular, debian

So I cannot install @angular/cli on my debian box. I have the latest nodejs, and npm installed. I have Angular4 running fine on my windows machine, and I use it everyday. My digital ocean droplet. I cannot get it running. I ahve tried everything I can think of. I have tried a string of fixes and the latest problem is this. I have tried to change the npm install directory, reinstall as root, as a user. Everything I can think of. Heres the read out

```
root@gentest:/var/site# npm install @angular/cli -g
/root/.npm-global/bin/ng -> /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> node-sass@4.5.3 install /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:502:3

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/lib/post_install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:502:3
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.3 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.3 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall: `node lib/post_install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-09-29T03_48_38_150Z-debug.log
root@gentest:/var/site#
```

When I try to run ng serve -o
in my angular4 app it says:

> NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your
>   browser on http://localhost:4200  10% building modules 3/3 modules 0
>   active(node:12295) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Exited with code 3

Any help would be very appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `node_modlues` folder

Then First try with :

Install it with : `sudo`

```
sudo npm install @angular/cli -g
```

In most of the case it works , and if it won't work then try with this

```
sudo npm install @angular/cli -g --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: well the unsafe worked to install but I am still getting, ** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active(node:15876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Exited with code 3                                      92% chunk asset optimizationKilled